# Bind image in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am using a gridview to display information on a page. The condition is that when I get Y from database result I need to bind `/images/goldx.png` Else `/images/check.gif` how can I do that I am using asp.net with vb.net as backend

```
<asp:GridView  ID="grdLocation" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  >
   <Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Monthly" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
     <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblLotName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("is_monthly") %>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:Image ID="resultImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("is_monthly") == 'Y'  ? "~/Images/check.gif" : "~/Images/goldx.png" %>' />
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
 <Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

My code for binding the Gridview :

```
Protected Function bindLocations()
    Try
        Dim _ds As DataSet
        If _locComp Is Nothing Then
            _locComp = New LocationComponent()
        End If
        _ds = _locComp.GetAllLots()

        If _ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            grdLocation.DataSource = _ds
            grdLocation.DataBind()

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Function
```

Thanks for your comment and answers .

Comment: Actually I don't know vb but i think you have to use rowdatabound event of gridview and you can catch the Y from database and use the appropriate image in image control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this check `OnRowDataBound` event of `GridView`. Like

```
Private Sub grdLocation_OnRowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdLocation.RowDataBound

 If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
  Dim lblLotNametxt as String = CType(e.Row.FindControl("lblLotName"),Label).Text
  If lblLotNametxt = "Y" Then
    CType(e.Row.FindControl("resultImage"),Image).ImageUrl = "~/Images/check.gif"
  Else
    CType(e.Row.FindControl("resultImage"),Image).ImageUrl = "~/Images/goldx.png"
  End If
 End If

End Sub
```

Hope this helps you.